# Cumulative sum in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, cumulative-sum

My data is as under :
Date   Total
01Aug   -10
02Aug   -5
03Aug   -15
04Aug   3
05Aug   -5

I want to add a sum total which
a. only add up when there is a positive number
b. only uses a negative number to reduce the positive total to 0

so the output should like below

Date   Total    Sum
01Aug   -10      0
02Aug   -5       0
03Aug   -15      0
04Aug   3        3
05Aug   -5       0

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be

sum(if(Data>0,Data,0))